# Jar from HTML

Tags: java, jar, javadoc

A third party library I'm utilizing provided the JavaDoc HTML and associated bin files in a zip file. How can I create a jar file from the JavaDoc HTML?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A JAR file is nothing but a ZIP file with an (optional) manifest file inside.

Basically, rename the file to .JAR and that's it.

Comment: Well, I haven't looked at the spec, and of course there's a lot of functionality that depends on information in the manifest, but I've yet to see any Java tool outright rejecting a JAR file just because it lacks a manifest.

Comment: Be sure that the index.html file is at the root of your .zip file (or your IDE won't be able to recognize it as javadoc).

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer: You can take all the files in a ZIP and put it .jar extension

Comment: A JAR file can be compressed, it may just lead to bad performance.

Answer (score 2):

JDK include jar.exe, for windows following path "%JAVA_HOME%/bin/jar.exe"

Supose you have folder

```
/somelib/
         packages.html
         ... other html
```

Go to the somelib directory:

```
cd /somelib/
jar cvf somelib-3.0-javadoc.jar *
```

After that in /somelib/ you can find somelib-3.0-javadoc.jar

Answer (score 1):

By zipping the files and renaming the compressed package .jar? ([JAR files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)#Overview) are basically just ZIP files.)

But why would you want to create a JAR out of the HTML files?

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering if it had to do with IDEs. With smart IDEs you wouldn't need to do such a thing, of course, as you can attach Javadocs directly from ZIPs/JARs/directories/URLs. :)

Comment: Your are correct. Is IDE related. I would much prefer to reference a URL.

Comment: That's possible at least in IntelliJ IDEA, and I believe in Eclipse too.

Answer (score -1):

Of course you could just unzip the zip file and add the lib folder you just decompressed to your classpath.